# Efficiently calculating containers hash codes

Tags: algorithm, hash, containers, time-complexity, hashcode

The algorithm I know about for calculating the hash code of containers works by combining the hash of all elements in it recursively. How the hashes are combined is irrelevant for my question. But because the algorithm recurses, the calculation can become very expensive. O(n), where *n* is the total number of elements reachable.

My question is if there are any more efficient methods to do it? For example, if you have an array with 100k elements, you could calculate the hash by combining the hash of only 100 of the elements contained. That would make the calculation 1000 times faster, while still being a good hash function, wouldn't it?

The 100 elements you pick could be the 100 first or every 1000th (in the above example) or picked using some other deterministic formula.

So to answer my question, can you *either* tell me why my idea can't work *or* tell me where my idea has already been investigated. Like has any programming language implemented "sub O(n) sequence hashing" like I'm proposing?

Comment: Hash for what purpose? If you use a commuting combination operator like XOR, then you can just update the hash whenever you manipulate the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, designing an appropriate hash function requires trading off computation time against quality, and this will be particularly true for very large objects.

Hashing only a fixed-size subset of a large object is a valid strategy (Lua uses this strategy for hashing large strings, for example), but it can obviously lead to problems if the hashed objects have few differences and it happens that the differences are not in the hashed subset. That opens the possibility of denial-of-service attacks (or inputs which accidentally trigger the same problem), so it is not generally a good idea if you are hashing uncontrolled inputs. (And if you're using the hash as part of a cryptographic exercise, then omitting part of the object makes falsification trivial, so in that context it's a really bad idea.)

Assuming you're using the hash as part of a database indexing strategy (that is, a hash table), remember that in the end you will need to compare the value being looked up with each potential match in the table; those comparisons are necessarily O(n) (unless you believe that almost all lookups will fail). Each false positive requires an additional comparison, so the quality-versus-computation-time tradeoff may turn out to be a false economy.

But, in the end, there is no definitive answer; you will have to decide based on the precise use case you have, including a consideration of what you are using the hash for, what the distribution of the data is (or is likely to be) and so on.

Comment: I don't understand your quality-vs-computation-time trade off. It seems my method would not require extra comparisons but would instead increase the risk (depending on data) of collisions in the hash table? Thanks for the Lua reference, I'll look at it. But there must be more people who have considered this trade off? I'm coming up with nothing when googling for it.

Comment: @björn: if there are more collisions, there will be more comparisons because you have to verify every hit. IMHO, it's not a common choice because (a) hashing very large objects is rare and (b) the cost of comparison cannot be avoided. (For large objects, computing the hash effectively preloads the cache, so the subsequent comparison is cheaper.) Of course, YMMV.